# How to solve Transfer function with step function appplied to the input?

Tags: transfer-function

I'm trying to solve this problem of the book "Automatic Control Systems" by Benjamin Kuo.
[image: Problem 3.1 of Automatic Control systems by B. Kuo]

I really don't get the answer the book has:

[image]

Since I thought the answer would have to be:

$$
F(s)=
\dfrac{880(s+6.818)}{s(s+6)(s+10)}
\dfrac{1}{s}
$$

or

$$
F(s)=
\dfrac{880(s+6.818)}{s(s+6)(s+10)}
E(s)
$$

since \$e(t)=u(t)\$

My question is why in the answer it seems they multiply \$F(s)/E_c(s)\$ by the step function since in the original function it is multiplying by the other side of the equation and there's only one instance of \$u(t)\$.
$$
\dfrac{1}{s}
G(s)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laplace transform \$F(s)\$ of the response of the system to a unit step input is   $$ F(s) = \frac{880. (1. s+6.81818)}{s (s+6.) (s+10.)} $$

The Laplace transform \$E(s)\$ of the input signal (unit step) is

$$ E(s) = \frac{1}{s} $$

The transfer function \$G(s)\$ relates the input and output by \$F(s)=G(s) E(s)\$.

Therefore, $$G(s)=\frac{F(s)}{E(s)} = \frac{880. (1. s+6.81818)}{(s+6.) (s+10.)}$$

Comment: I now understand the last part as how you add the input to the equation and since it has a relation to the step function you just add it in both sides of the equation, but
why do you calculate the laplace transform of the response system with out taking in account the step function.
$$f(t)=100(1-0.3e^-6*t-0.7e^-10*t)$$
Instead of calculating it like the whole equation that its shown.
$$f(t)=100(1-0.3e^-6t-0.7e^-10t)u(t)$$

Comment: I did take it into account. The two equations you have are the same for \$t \geq 0\$, because \$ u(t) = 1 \$ for \$t \geq 0\$.