# Transfer function of controller

Tags: control-system, laplace-transform

[image]

I am solving this question given in book (Automatic control system). As asked in (a) part \$G_c(s)\$ of the controller. I solved it and getting answer$$G_c(s) = \frac{F(s)}{E_c(s)}=\frac{100}{s}-\frac{30}{s+6}+\frac{70}{s+10}$$ but the answer in manual is $$G_c(s) = \frac{F(s)}{E_c(s)}=s\left(\frac{100}{s}-\frac{30}{s+6}+\frac{70}{s+10}\right)$$ 
I know laplace transform and i am not too mature in control theory so please help in solving this question.
I want to know from where this \$s\$ in multiplication is coming.

Comment: What you call G(s) in your result is F(s), you need to multiply the result by s to find G(s). You have F(s)=G(s)*1/s

Comment: Same question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173254/how-to-solve-transfer-function-with-step-function-appplied-to-the-input

Answer (score 2):

In fact, what you define as G(s) in your solution is just F(s):

$$F(t)= 100 * (1-0,3e^{-6t}-0,7e^{-10t})u(t)$$ and $$u(t) = 1 $$

u(t) is the step function
When you apply the laplace transform you will get:`

$$F(s)=\frac{100}{s}-\frac{30}{s+6}-\frac{70}{s+10}=G(s)\frac{1}{s}$$ 1/s is the transformation of the step function.
So, to find G(s) you have to multiply by s the result of F(s).